# When I try to add a new product to my PRODUCTS group in the Django Admin site it gives me a no such table: main.auth_user__old error

Tags: python, django

I've been learning python and Im having a problem when I try to add another user/group or anything in the admin page for Django. When I try to save it brings me to a page that says OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old.
I've been looking around and Ive found no fix for the problem I would like some help. This is some of the code.
This is my models.py code.

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=4036)


class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

This is the main url.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]
```

This is the secondary url.py code in my products folder

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    
    #
    # /products/1/detail
    # /products/new
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index),
        path('new', views.new)
    ]
```

This is the views.py code

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render
    
    
    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello World')
    
    
    def new(request):
        return HttpResponse('New Products')
```

and finally this is the admin.py code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import Product

admin.site.register(Product)
```

Does anyone know a fix for why when I try to add another product to my PRODUCTS group in the Django admin site and save it is says

```
OperationalError at /admin/products/product/add/
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: main.auth_user__old
Exception Location: C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your migration has been done correctly and that you have not changed significant attributes of the product model since the last migration.

Also check you database connection

Comment: Yea the models are fine so that's not the problem and my database connection is also fine. I dont know whats happening with it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in pycharm and it did work:

```
    pip install Django --upgrade
```

Then

```
    python manage.py migrate
    python manage.py makemigrations 'app_name'
    python manage.py migrate
```

Put that in the terminal.
It took me like 5 hours to find the fix but this does work on pycharm!